# Calling Global Variable from Controller to HTML View AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following code in Plunkr.  http://plnkr.co/edit/8sBafktFzFa8fCLLJgMF

this is my js file

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {



  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalDemoCtrl',
      size: size
    });

    var applicantID = 12;
  };


  $scope.submit_info = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent1.html',
      controller: 'ModalDemoCtrl',
      size: size
    });
  };
});
```

this is my html page

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">

            <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>

            <button class="btn btn-default"  ng-click="submit_info('lg')">Submit</button>

    </script>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent1.html">

            <h3>CaseID: </h3>
            {{ applicantID }}

    </script>

    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Set caseID</button>

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to be able to assign applicantID upon clicking the button "setID" and upon clicking button "submit",it displays the applicantID value that was passed which is '12'. But it keeps passing an empty data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind it with $rootScope:-

```
$rootScope.applicantID = 12;
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fQnwvAUSioNj0P4mOve2?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You have to associate the applicantID variable with the scope. only then you can access it in the view.

```
    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

      $scope.applicantID = 12;
      .
      .

    });
```

Updated Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DiSoJyJ4ufnDf1nqo8Ky?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer , if i understand your problem in right way .

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {



  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalPopupCtrl,
      size: size
    });

    var applicantID = 12;
  };






});

  function ModalPopupCtrl($scope,$modal){

  $scope.applicantID = 12;

  $scope.submit_info = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent1.html',
      controller: ModalPopupCtrl,
      size: size
    });
  };
}
```